# Laravel 9: Why SweetAlert2's confirm delete popup disappears immediately and deletes data before confirming?

Tags: javascript, laravel, sweetalert2

I am trying to add SweetAlert2 to `<a href="#">` which is responsible for handling data delete. This is the HTML in blade:

```
<a  href="{{ route('data-entry.lost-and-found.destroy', $lostFound) }}"
    onclick="deleteConfirm(formId)"
    data-id="{{ $lostFound->id }}"
    data-toggle="tooltip"
    class="dropdown-item px-3 btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger btn-active-light-danger">
       Delete
</a>
```

and this is the sweetAlert function within the same blade file:

```
<script>
    const formId = document.getElementById('LFform');

    window.deleteConfirm = function(formId) {
        swal.fire({
            icon: 'warning',
            text: 'Are you sure you wan to delete this?',
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonText: 'Delete',
            confirmButtonColor: '#e3342f',
            dangerMode: true,
        }).then((result) => {
            if (result.isConfirmed) {
                formId.submit();
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

It is working, but there is a bug that makes the popup disappear and deletes the data before I actually click on the "confirm" button

[image]

Comment: what is output of `result.isConfirmed` ? from [docs](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-buttons) you could make use of `value` key for boolean check

Comment: update the `href="javascript:;"` value of `a` tag, then use the Ajax in you if condition, you are doing both loading href and onclick event at same time and your window is reloading for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way,

```
swal({
    text: 'Are you sure you wan to delete this?',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: !0,
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then(function (e) {
    if (e.value) {
      console.log('Delete Confirmed');
    } else {
      console.log('Delete Cancelled');
    }
});
```